# Light detector for row of LEDs

Tags: led, ldr

Today I created this circuit and it works fine:

[image: Working light detector]

Now I want to replace the single LED with this row of LEDs:

[image: Multiple LED array]

But after this all the LEDs have a low brightness. How can I get back the brightness of the LEDs to a similar level to that of a single LED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it by replacing R2 and D1, with an array. While the way you want it has 8 leds in parallel, without resistors, a more efficient way would be this (I'm assuming a ~2v led, and based on that 8~9mA per led [(6v Source - 2v LED Forward Voltage) / 470Ω = 8mA]. 4 parallel strings of 2 Leds in series with a 220Ω resistor. 32mA of current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhqmXd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Otherwise you would have 8 parallel strings of 1 led + 470Ω resistor. The BC547 you use is more than enough to handle the 8mA * 8 strings of current (64mA, it can handle 100mA)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwn3Tx.png)</sup>

Comment: +1, a better answer than mine.

Comment: it works fine. thanks. and thanks @AnindoGhosh. i understand what was my problem

Answer (score 2):

Without validating the circuit provided in the question, here is a minor addition that should address the brightness issue *partly* (*see note at end*).

A MOSFET is switched by the same operating point in the original schematic, as was switching the single LED on or off. This removes the dependency of LED brightness on the emitter current of the BJT Q2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc6kZi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gain and thus switching sharpness of the pair of BJTs has not been compromised from the original, partly because I was lazy. **BJT Q2 could very well be replaced by the MOSFET directly**, if so desired.

---

**Note:**

What this does *not* solve, is the issue around the current drive capability of the power source. If the 6 Volt supply in the design is not able to supply the current demands of the multitude of LEDs, that will simply require the supply source to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should duplicate both R2 and D1: one current limiting resistor per LED. There will however be an overall limit on how much current you can put through the transistor limiting how many LEDs you can connect to it.

Comment: i add R2 before each LED. and brightness is low. what is that? `"current limiting resistor"` ?

Comment: That's R2: it's the current limiting resistor. Does it work with just 2 LEDs in parallel rather than 10? Are they all the same as the original LED?

Comment: no. brightness is low. and test just for two parallel led, and its low bright.